# How to join a table with itself?

Tags: sql

I want to ask how can I join the table with itself, using the same column twice, and giving each a different WHERE to sort out. I have an Employees table that contain Employee_name, job_id and manager_id. I want it to get the name of all the managers through the job_id on one column, and then all the employees that they manage on the other column. This is what I came up with :

```
SELECT A.LAST_NAME AS MANAGER_NAME, B.LAST_NAME AS EMPLOYEES_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES A
RIGHT JOIN EMPLOYEES B
ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE A.JOB_ID LIKE '%MAN%'
AND A.MANAGER_ID = B.MANAGER_ID
```

This simply put the manager name on both columns, and I don't have another idea on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: what about ```ON A.MANAGER_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_ID```?

Comment: @Kristian yes that was silly of me not to think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join condition needs to change, the `WHERE` criteria should be moved to the `ON` clause, and also I would use a left join here:

```sql
SELECT emp1.LAST_NAME AS EMPLOYEES_NAME, COALESCE(emp2.LAST_NAME, 'NA') AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES emp1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES emp2
    ON emp2.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID AND emp2.JOB_ID LIKE '%MAN%';
```

It is unclear whether you even need the check on the `JOB_ID`, but in any case I use `COALESCE` above to display `NA` as the manager name for any employee not having a manager.

Comment: . . I am not going to upvote an answer that uses meaningless table aliases.